# Oracle SQL> SSRS output > MS-Word envelop formatting issue

Tags: reporting-services, ms-word, oracle-sqldeveloper, envelope

We are trying to providing MS-Word's Mail-Envelope facility to end users.

- Address is being fetched from oracle database as below:

  ```
  AddressLine1 || chr(10) || chr(13) ||
  AddressLine2 || chr(10) || chr(13) ||
  CityAndZip || chr(10) || chr(13) as Address
  ```
- Then in SSRS report output is showing like this, which is expected:

  ```
  1234 SomeRoad
  SomeOther Address
  SomeCity 12345
  ```
- When this SSRS report is exported into Word file, the output still looks the same. However if you look closely you will see at the end of line we have 'line feed' and  'carriage return character'. With data if you tried to use Mail-Envelop facility then the address doesn't comes into address box automatically.

  ```
  1234 SomeRoad↵
  SomeOther Address↵
  SomeCity 12345↵
  ```
- If we change these 'return characters' into paragraph Symbols manually. By going at the end of each line and press delete(the next line comes up) and then press enter(the addressline goes to line below again). This will remove the return character(↵) to paragraph character (¶). Then if you go to mail-Envelope option then address will be populated properly.

  ```
  1234 SomeRoad¶ 
  SomeOther Address¶ 
  SomeCity 12345¶
  ```

Approaches we have tried:

1. Used variations with chr(10) and chr(13), every time the problem comes to same formatting.
2. Tried to insert paragraph character directly from SQL by using chr(0182). This inserts paragraph symbol but it is treated as special character(Comes as it is) and not the actual paragraph symbol from the word.

Please suggest if there is other way to resolve this problem. Or if there is better approach to satisfy the requirement itself. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so what we have used is placeholders in SSRS report. Insider text box, put some placeholders, that are generating '¶' and next line when export into word. You can add some static text along with placeholders(for dynamic data). With this we don't need to change SQL for getting data in particular format.
E.g. 
`Address:
[Placeholder-AddressLine1],
[Placeholder-AddressLine2]
[Placeholder-CityAndZip]`

Answer (score 0):

The paragraph symbol in Word is ANSI 13, only. Any other combination, such as the ANSI 10 + ANSI 13 you're currently exporting to Word, will not be recognized correctly. Simply strip out the ANSI 10 and you should get the expected result.

Comment: We have already tried with only chr(13). It didn't help. Also as I mentioned chr(13) is giving carriage return but not the paragraph symbol. Paragraph symbol only appears when you actually press enters in word doc.

Comment: @SandipPawar No, you don't mention any of that in your question. But in any case. ANSI 13 is what generates the paragraph symbol in Word documents. If you don't believe me, open a Word document (a "real" one, not one generated by a tool), select the paragraph mark, then run ` ?Asc(Selection.Text)`  in the Immediate Window of the VBA Editor. Possibly these documents contain other content that's causing a problem.

Comment: thanks for your response. I believe you regarding fact about chr(13). In the approaches I had mention that we have tired few combination with chr(10) and chr(13). So initially we tried only with chr(13), because we were expecting that it will give us the next line. It does give a next line. However it is not giving the paragraph symbol when we export the SSRS report output into word. It shows (↵) character. With this visually we see address lines are on separate lines. However mail-envelope is failing to pickup the address correctly.

Comment: I verified for other characters, they are no other special characters. So when we export SSRS report to word, may be SSRS is interpreting these chr(13) to (↵) and not the (¶).

Comment: I'm not familiar with SSRS, but just for information the symbol you show with the arrow usually denotes ANSI 11. If yoiu can confirm they are ANSI 11 (or any other specific character) it would be possible to use Find/Replace in Word to replace them with the "right" paragraph mark if SSRS won't export in a format Word prefers.